# Adding "NSLog" when release occured "Expected unqualified-id" in NSObjCRuntime.h

Tags: ios, release, nslog

```
 but had error:"Expected unqualified-id" in NSObjCRuntime.h
```

for NSLog nothing, I added code in "prefixHeader.pch"

```
#ifndef __OPTIMIZE__

#define NSLog(...) NSLog(__VA_ARGS__) //avoid nslog when release
#else
# define NSLog(...) {}  
#endif
```

Answer (score 0):

add these code，OK!

```
#ifdef __OBJC__

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

#endif
```